# Writing a log-likelihood as a function in R (what is theta?)

Tags: r, function, log-likelihood

I have the following log-likelihood from my model which i am trying to write as a function in R.

[image]

My issue come as i dont know how to write theta in terms of the the function. I have had a couple of attempts at this as shown below, any tips/advice on if these are close to being correct could be appreciated.

function with theta written as theta

```
#my likelihood function
mylikelihood = function(beta) {

#log-likelihood
result = sum(log(dengue$cases + theta + 1 / dengue$cases)) +
  sum(theta*log(theta / theta + exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$time))) + 
  sum(theta * log(exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$time / dengue$cases + exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$time))))

#return negative log-likelihood
return(-result)
}
```

my next attempt with thetas replaced with Xi from my dataset, which here is (dengue$time)

```
#my likelihood function attempt 2
mylikelihood = function(beta) {

#log-likelihood
result = sum((log(dengue$Cases + dengue$Time + 1 / dengue$Cases))) +
sum(dengue$Time*log(dengue$time / dengue$Time + exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$Time))) + 
sum(dengue$Cases * log(exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$Time / dengue$Cases + 
exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*dengue$Time))))

 #return negative log-likelihood
 return(-result)
 }
```

data

```
   head(dengue)
  Cases Week Time
1   148   36    1
2   275   37    2
3   205   38    3
4   133   39    4
5   123   40    5
6   138   41    6
```

Are either of these close to being correct, and if not where am I going wrong?

Updated into about where the log-likelihood comes from;

The model;

[image]

Negative Binomial distribution with mean µ and dispersion parameter θ has pmf;

[image]

Comment: You have forgotten parenthesis after division
a/b+c is no equal a/(b+c)

Comment: Note that your likelihood is written as `L(parameters; DATA)` so theta is just a parameter as Beta is.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about where your log-likelihood function comes from/is derived?

Comment: @BenBolker Sure i can upload the model and distribution in the question

Comment: You should probably try to be more careful when transcribing equations into R - there are several important mistakes here (see my answer) which would have messed you up even if everything else were coded perfectly ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you have to pass both `beta` (intercept and slope of one component of the problem) and `theta` as part of a single parameter vector. You had other problems with parenthesis placement that I fixed, and I reorganized the expressions a little bit.

There are several more important mistakes in your code.

- The first term is **not a fraction**; it is a binomial coefficient. (i.e., you should use `lchoose()`, as shown below)
- You changed a +1 to a -1 in the first term.

```r
nll <- function(pars) {                                                                                      
    beta <- pars[1:2]                                                                                        
    theta <- pars[3]                                                                                         
                                                                                                             
    ##log-likelihood                                                                                         
    yi <- dengue$Cases                                                                                       
    xi <- dengue$Time                                                                                        
    ri <- exp(beta[1]+beta[2]*xi)                                                                            
    result <- sum(lchoose(yi + theta - 1,yi)) +                                                              
        sum(theta*log(theta / (theta + ri))) +                                                               
        sum(yi * log(ri/(theta+ri)))                                                                         
    ##return negative log-likelihood                                                                         
    return(-result)                                                                                          
}
```

### read data

```r
dengue <- read.table(row.names = 1, header = TRUE, text = "                                                  
 Cases Week Time                                                                                             
1   148   36    1                                                                                            
2   275   37    2                                                                                            
3   205   38    3                                                                                            
4   133   39    4                                                                                            
5   123   40    5                                                                                            
6   138   41    6                                                                                            
")
```

### fitting

Guessing starting parameters of (1,1,1) is a bit dangerous - it would make more sense to know something about the *meaning* of the parameters and guess biologically plausible values - but it seems to be OK.

```r
nll(c(1,1,1))                                                                                                
optim(par = c(1,1,1), nll)
```

Since we didn't constrain theta to be positive we get some warnings about taking the log of a negative number, but these are probably harmless (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394494/coding-likelihood-and-log-likelihood-function-in-r-to-perform-optimization/72411784#72411784))

---

### alternatives

R has a lot of built-in machinery for fitting negative binomial models (I should have recognized what you were doing!)

`MASS::glm.nb` sets everything up for you automatically, you just have to specify the predictor variables (it uses a logarithmic link and adds an intercept, so specifying `~Time` will make the mean equal to `exp(beta0 + beta1*Time)`).

```r
library(MASS)
glm.nb(Cases ~ Time, data = dengue)
```

`bbmle` is a little bit less automated, but more flexible (here I am fitting `theta` on the log scale to avoid trying any negative values)

```r
library(bbmle)
mle2(Cases ~ dnbinom(mu = exp(logmu), size = exp(logtheta)),
                     parameters = list(logmu ~ Time),
                     data = dengue,
                     start = list(logmu = 0, logtheta = 0))
```

All three of these approaches (corrected negative log-likelihood function + `optim`, `MASS::glm.nb`, `bbmle::mle2`) give the same results.